# how to set max resolution for each features in openlayers3

Tags: openlayers-3

Hello i am trying to do different styles for different features and i got and working fine,now i want to set different resolution for different features.I tried doing this way but not working.Can u please Help this?

```
style: function (feature, resolution) {
            //var test = (resolution >= 200) ? (feature.get('class') === 'xx') : '';
            //resolution: test;

            if (feature.get('class') === '---') {

                max Resolution: 100;
                return style1;
            }
            else if (feature.get('class') === 'xx')
            {

                return Style2;
            }
            else if (feature.get('class') === '---')
            {

                return style3;

            }
            else if(feature.get('class')==='ii')
            {

                return style4;
            }
            else if(feature.get('class')==='mm')
            {
                return style5;
            }
        },
```

Comment: You can use `map.getView().setResolution(...)` inside your conditions.

Comment: Thank you but i am not getting,i am trying to do this way getting error like map.getView.setResolution is not a function() map.getView.setResolution('200') and map.getView.setResolution(res)

Comment: Setting the view resolution in a style function does not make sense. If I understand @indu correctly, the goal is to show certain feature only up to a certain resolution.

Comment: yes you are correct ahocevar, i want to set different resolution for different features.can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to resolve this with simple boolean logic. Something like this:

```
style: function(feature, resolution) {
  var class = feature.get('class');
  if (resolution >= 200) {
    if (class == 'xx') {
      return style200xx;
    } else if (class == 'xy') {
      return style200xy;
    }
  } else if (resolution < 200) {
    if (class == 'xx') {
      return style0xx;
    } else if (class == 'xy') {
      return style0xy;
    }
  }
}
```

If you have many different cases, it might make sense to define a separate `ol.layer.Vector` for each resolution range, and use the same `source` for all layers. Inside the style functions, you will then only have to handle the feature class.

Comment: Thanks you so much it is working fine for my problem